# Alternating header titles

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to figure out how to get the odd and pages to display the *current section* name and the odd pages to display the title of the paper.

How do I accomplish this?

I'm using `article` and I have `fancyhdr` loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\hdrtitle}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Some Author}

\makeatletter
\let\hdrtitle\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed that the pages shift left and right (as if written for a book). How do I remove that feature?

Comment: @AlanH I am not sure what do you mean with "pages shift left and right". Perhaps that inner/outer margins are different for even and odd pages? If this is so, then you could load the `geometry` package with the `centering` option: `\usepackage[centering]{geometry}`. If you meant other thing, please explain in a little more detail.

Comment: When I use your code, the section number will display. It's quite confusing because the section number and the page number are both in the header. How do I just display the section title without the numbering?

Comment: @AlanH just now I saw your comment; I see you opened a new question, with this issue. I've provided an answer to this new question.

Answer (score 1):

[`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) is an intuitive alternative to [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) which provides `\*title` macros the contain the sectional unit titles (in contrast to using `article`'s `\leftmark`, that has no immediate context).

Pilfering an example structure from Gonzalo:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Some Author}

\makeatletter
\let\hdrtitle\@title% To store the title after using \maketitle
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \sethead[\thepage][][\thesection \quad \sectiontitle] % even
  {\hdrtitle}{}{\thepage}} % odd
\makeatother
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The main driver for setting headers/footers is given by

```
\sethead[<left>][<centre>][<right>] % even header
  {<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}} % odd header
\setfoot[<left>][<centre>][<right>] % even footer
  {<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}} % odd footer
```

which are self-explanatory.

Comment: what would be the advantage of this over Gonzalo's?

Comment: @AlanH: Extracting other sectional unit titles where needed (`\subsectiontitle`, ...), and perhaps extracting so-called top/bottom title marks (typically associated with dictionary-style headings). You'd have to see the full [`titleps` documentation](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titleps.pdf) for more on this. There's also a short section on [`titleps` for `fan­cy­hdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html), if you're interested.